# Upper bound on the sum of means.

Tags: inequality, asymptotics, means

I was looking at a previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870904/the-mean-of-the-of-a-sum-is-the-sum-of-the-means), and was curious to the following extension:

Suppose I have positive integers $x_1,\dots,x_n$, and another positive integer $m<n$. If we were to arbitrarily group the indices into two disjoint sets $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, such that $|\mathcal{A}|=m$ and $|\mathcal{B}|=n-m$ (also $A\cup B=\{1,\dots,n\}$), is there an upper bound as a function of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ (or $\frac{1}{n-m}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$) for the following sum of means when $m=o(n)$?
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{A}}x_i+\frac{1}{n-m}\sum_{j\in\mathcal{B}}x_j.
\end{align*}
For example, if $n=m-n$ (i.e., $m=\frac{n}{2}$), then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{A}}x_i+\frac{1}{n-m}\sum_{j\in\mathcal{B}}x_j
=\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i.
\end{align*}
I'm curious about the upper bound for the more general case of $m=o(n)$.

**Clarification:**
I'm considering the scenario where the groups are already given to us (we can't choose what to put in each group). I was wondering if we can get an upper bound of constant * $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ (or $\frac{1}{n-m}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$), i.e., something similar to the case of $m=n-m$.

Comment: To clarify, do the sets form a partition (i.e. they are also disjoint)?

Comment: Yes. They are disjoint, I've updated the question.

Comment: If the groups are given, then the two averages are fixed.  What are you looking for when you ask for "bound"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is certainly no constant $C$ for which there is an upper bound of the form $Cn^{-1}\sum_1^nx_i$. Take $m=n-1$, take $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1}$ to be small, say, $x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_{n-1}=1$, and $x_n$ to be some large number $L$. Then $n^{-1}\sum_1^nx_i=(n-1+L)/n=(L/n)+1-(1/n)$, while the other sum is $1+L$, which is almost $n$ times as big.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $m\lt n-m$.  Put the $m$ largest in A and the rest in B.  This will give you the upper bound.  Proof: obvious - any switch will make the sum lower.

Detail of proof: $x_k \in A$ and $x_j\in B$ $\frac{x_k}{m}+\frac{x_j}{n-m}\gt \frac{x_j}{m}+\frac{x_k}{n-m}$ since $\frac{x_k-x_j}{m}\gt \frac{x_k-x_j}{n-m}$.

Obvious note: $m\gt n-m$, switch roles.

Comment: I thought $m$ was also allowed to vary, and that the question was asking for a bound over all values of $m$ ($1\le m\le n-1$).

Comment: My reading is for a bound for any m, not for all at once.  Resu should clarify.

Comment: Sorry for not wording it well. I was looking at the scenario where the groups are already given to us (we can't choose what to put in each group). I was wondering if we can get an upper bound of constant * $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_j$. I.e., Gerry's understanding is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I've made the required updates to the question.